# is there a function in sql to find second minimum in table, which then used in case

Tags: sql

For example, there are two tables, and in one - prices with articles, and another table - checks, some articles in checks, and quantity of article

### `TABLE checks`

| checks | art | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1check | 1toy | 2 |
| 1check | 1toy | 5 |
| 1check | 1toy | 1 |
| 1check | 2toy | 1 |
| 1check | 4toy | 3 |
| 2check | 2toy | 1 |
| 2check | 1toy | 2 |

### `TABLE articles`

| art | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1toy | 2.00 |
| 2toy | 2.50 |
| 3toy | 1.50 |
| 4toy | 6.00 |
| 1toy | 2.50 |
| 1toy | 3.00 |

and i need to count the sum of sales of 1check,where i need to take the second minimum of price if the articles repeat.
for 1toy in 1check the price have to be 2.5.- for sum (quantity*price)
i try to write a code - but i finally confused.
help please

```sql
SELECT
    a.check,
    Sump
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            price2,
            Case
                WHEN COUNT( a.art ) > 1 THEN
                    SUM( a.quantity * a.price ) 
                ELSE
                    SUM( a.quantity * price2 )
            END AS sump,
            a.art,
            a.check
        FROM
            checks AS a
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    art,
                    price,
                    LEAD( price, 1 ) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY art
                        ORDER BY price ASC
                    ) AS price2
            FROM
                prices
            ) AS b on a.art = b.art
        WHERE
            a.quantity > 0
        GROUP BY
            a.checks,
            a.art,
            price2
    )
WHERE
    a.checks = '1check'
```

Comment: This is identical yo your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74011142/is-there-a-function-in-sql-to-find-second-minimum-in-table-wich-then-used-in-ca). You should edit your question to provide the requested details and clarity. And the yes/no answer to this question is no, you will need to write some sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `ROW_NUMBER()` and `COUNT` window functions as the following:

```
SELECT T.checks, T.art, SUM(T.quantity * D.price) sump
  FROM
  checks T JOIN
  ( 
    SELECT art, price,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY art) cn,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY art ORDER BY price) rn
    FROM articles
  ) D
ON T.art = D.art
WHERE (D.cn = 1 OR D.rn = 2) AND T.checks = '1check'
GROUP BY T.checks, T.art
ORDER BY T.checks, T.art
```

The `WHERE (D.cn = 1 OR D.rn = 2)` ensures that the returned price is the second minimum (rn=2) or it's only the existed price (cn=1).

The output according to your provided data:

| CHECKS | ART | SUMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1check | 1toy | 20 |
| 1check | 2toy | 2.5 |
| 1check | 4toy | 18 |

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T01Mlmqn) on Oracle 11g.

Comment: prices come up and down and a price in a certain date can equal a price on a different date. You probably want to use dense_rank() and not row_number()

Comment: Hi @DannySlor, I didn't understand, what date? there is no date column in the table. The OP wants to find the sum according to the second minimum price, and that is what I did.

Comment: You're assuming that two prices can never be the same. A date is just an example. Different vendors is another one. If it's for homework you're right and it doesn't matter, if not then I think dense_rank() is better

Comment: One art may have multiple prices, I used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY art ORDER BY price)` this will guarantee the selection of the second minimum price for each art.

Comment: thank u, it works. But there is no condition about that is art repeats. We see that the price repeat, because the table is small, and what to do when we do not see this

Comment: If the price is repeated for an art value the cn will be >1 and then take the price where rn=2, if there is only one price for an art the cn will be =1. That is how this query works.

Comment: great. thank u. u've made a discovery for me. I didn't get that this query with 'or' doesn't stop the selection.  because when write smth like (where d.cn>1 and d.rn =1) - it just find all with this and stop

Answer (score 1):

We use `dense_rank()` to find the second lowest price in the case `count(*) > 1`. Then we merge the tables, group by art and total the sales.

```
with a  as (
select  art
       ,price
from   
        (
        select   a.*
                ,dense_rank() over(partition by art order by price) as dns_rnk
                ,count(*) over(partition by art)                    as cnt
        from    articles a
        ) a 
where   cnt > 1 and dns_rnk = 2
or      cnt = 1 
          )

  
select   art
        ,sum(quantity)*price as total
from     a left join checks c using(art)
group by art, price, checks
having   checks = '1check'
order by art
```

| ART | TOTAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1toy | 20 |
| 2toy | 2.5 |
| 4toy | 18 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CXFvGCjd)

Comment: thank u, looks great, but 2toy - 2.5.

Comment: Do you want the results by checks? There is toy2 in 1check and 2check so I got 5. Let me know and I'll fix it

Comment: yep, it is for only 1check. but i get the idea. thank u

Comment: still... see updated answer